# How can I select random UV mesh faces?

Tags: uv

There used to be a feature in 2.8 called "Select Random" but they seem to have removed it. The highlighted areas are the kind of effect I'm trying to achieve. [image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Select Random* is in the 3D view, not in the *UV Editor*, once you've selected in the 3D view, it will select the UVs in the *UV Editor* as well.

Comment: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `thanks!!!`